# Change I2C Speed in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, i2c

I am using linux based kits and I have a problem about changing i2c speed.
Do you know how to change in linux which has the version 3.4.39

Comment: i2c speed on what device?

Comment: ARM-Embedded-S5P4418-Single-Board-Computer

Comment: Maybe you should ask this question on [Electronics SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)..

Comment: ok, I will also ask in this platform.Thank you for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using ARM, you can define the I2C speed at boot time in the [devicetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_tree).
I am making some assumptions here (eg. that you are using [U-boot](https://www.denx.de/wiki/U-Boot) as bootloader), but embedded systems tend to look very similar.

1. Locate your devicetree. It is specified during boot and probably located in /boot/ 
   (You can also type *printenv* in U-boot shell and look for a variable called devicetree)
2. [Disassemble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670967/how-to-compile-dts-linux-device-tree-source-files-to-dtb) your devicetree to dts-format (device-tree-source)
3. Change the i2c-speed parameter (Search for "i2c" and "clock-frequency"
   clock-frequency = < some_speed_in_HZ >;"
4. Compile it back to *.dtb (device-tree-blob) and store it as a *my_devicetree.dtb* in /boot/

on the next reboot, in the bootloader menu choose *my_devicetree.dtb* as *devicetree-file* and it should work.

Comment: unfortunately in my /boot/  ,there is nothing and when I type prientenv there is no such as devicetree word.

Comment: what about dtb_file or something similar?

Comment: in boot ,there is no file . it is empty.What do you think is it possible that  dtb file would be in different location.

Comment: It could be on another partition or another storage device. The easiest would be to analyse the "printenv"-output from uboot. There will be some information which file is being served the kernel as devicetree and where it is located.